# Manage to get HTTPS response with CURL but not from browser

Tags: node.js, excel, http, curl, powerquery

Probably a stupid question, but I'm struggling. I want to connect to an API URL.
I managed to get a response from Shell using CURL, but when I try to set a href link correctly to get the answer displayed in the browser, it doesn't work (I actually want to set it up EXCEL power query afterwards).

The instructions are as follow:
[image]

I assembled the following CURL:

```
curl https://proranktracker.com/api/?command=urls.get --user "abcabc@gmail.com":"password"
```

I'm looking for a way to set a URL link that contains the necessary info to get the result via browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't set custom headers directly from a URL link in a browser.  You could construct an Ajax call from Javascript in a browser with the custom headers.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it out. The most stupid error I didn't think of... the password contained the char "&". Therefore, when sending it via browser, it broke the password for 2 different pieces.
I removed this special Char and now it works just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you are not the only one who experienced this.